# My guy syndrome - DM edition

Tags: gm-techniques, system-agnostic, new-gm

I've currently read [this](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37103/what-is-my-guy-syndrome-and-how-do-i-handle-it/#37105) question about the so-called *My Guy* syndrome, and since I recently started DM-ing myself, I couldn't help but wonder - is there an equivalent of this for a DM?
A short summary of the syndrome as I understand it:

*My Guy* syndrome is when you make your character do something, just because you believe that it's what your character - *your guy* - would do, despite the fact that taking that course of action would upset everyone (OOC), ruin the fun in playing the game and be highly detrimental to the atmosphere.

Now, if you are the DM, you don't have *your guy*, but you have lots of *guys*, and one of those guys (particularly monstrous ones) might one day happen to be in a situation where *that guy* would kill a player (not knock him unconscious), even though there are other party members nearby.
I don't have a specific example right now (feel free to edit and add one), but it could be, for example, something along the lines of a fiend that draws particular power from obtaining a creature's soul.

---

The particular situation doesn't matter, just assume that the creature,  lore-wise, would prefer to finally kill an unconscious, near-dead character as opposed to knocking out another, non-unconscious one (I'm using D&D 5e terms here, but just replace "unconscious" with whatever would be near-death in your system - maybe simply low hit points).

#### So, to my actual question: Have you experienced this situation as a DM, and if so, how did your players react to you killing the player? Or if you decided against killing the player, was there any particular reaction, aside from a to-be-expected sigh of relief?

*Please differentiate depending on whether or not the party has access to means of reviving a dead character.*

Comment: those that voted for closing - would you care to elaborate? It's a theoretical situation that is likely to occur in every campaign at some point. If you feel that it's too broad, let me know why so that ***I*** can elaborate.

Comment: I voted to close because it doesn't feel like a question that has an answer. It's asking for people to weigh in with their experience, not to answer a question.

Comment: alright, I rephrased the emphasized question so that it relies more on facts than on people's personal evaluation of the described situation. Mind you, of course it relies a little on experience - but that doesn't necessarily make it unfit for this site, in my opinion. Stackexchange is about providing answers to questions, and this is **most certainly** a question that many DMs will come across and seek an answer for. However, you can **only** answer it with experience, not with rules in a player handbook or anything like that.

Comment: I'm putting this on hold briefly as "have you experienced this, how did it go?" is a survey, not a request for a solution. Notably a survey answer may contain no solution whatsoever; it's just an expression of "well, this stuff happpened." This needs to be rephrased to actually request solutions to the problem. I can't do that right now, unfortunately, since I have only a minute or two left, so I'm going to have to hand this over to the wider community to guide you in reaching those goals. ([chat] may be able to help. Note someone should link back to the transcript here in comments.)

Comment: For the purposes of your question, does "DM My Guy Syndrome" only cover killing player characters? Or can it include other myguyish behavior?

Comment: This happens in C2E26 of Critical Role.